# Why is MySQL applying WHERE before LEFT JOIN when it's less efficient?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with about 2m records that I'm joining with a much smaller table, producing a set of about 2k records. This joining takes 0.13 second to process. If I apply a WHERE condition referencing fields in the 2m record table however, the query takes 17+ seconds to process. It appears to me that the MySQL engine is deciding to apply the WHERE clause before the JOIN even though in this case that is much less efficient. Can anyone help me understand why MySQL is doing this and how I can get it to apply the WHERE clause after the JOIN? I've put example tables below to better help illustrate the problem:

```
Table BigTable {
  SmallTableId: int,
  result: varchar
}

Table SmallTable {
  id: int
}

SELECT * FROM SmallTable
LEFT JOIN BigTable on BigTable.smallTableId = SmallTable.id
-- This takes 0.13 seconds to process and produces ~2k rows

SELECT * FROM SmallTable
LEFT JOIN BigTable on BigTable.smallTableId = SmallTable.id
WHERE result = 'ERROR'
-- This takes 17 seconds to process
```

My uninformed naive idea about the optimal way to complete the second query would be to generate the result set of the first query (about 2k rows in 0.13 seconds), and then apply the WHERE condition to that, which would be trivial in terms of process time to apply to 2k records. Clearly it's not doing that though.

I've tried making the first query a sub-query to try to get MySQL to generate it first but that has no effect:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM SmallTable
  LEFT JOIN BigTable on BigTable.smallTableId = SmallTable.id
) as t
WHERE t.result = 'ERROR'
-- Still takes 17 seconds
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Your join is a left join. It wouldn't make a difference whether it was executed first or last (I'm fairly certain it's last). Your join is taking everything from the left table, joining it to what it can on the right table, and filling the columns with `NULL` if there is no corresponding entry. There's no difference between this query with the join and this query without the join (other than you wouldn't get data from the other table).

Comment: MySQL might generally assume that joining smaller temporary results will be more efficient than filtering after joining.

Comment: You'd simply create suitable index.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions. Specially add the table definitions so we can see the indices you have added in your tables. Also add the result of [`EXPLAIN` queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-execution-plan) for both your SQL queries to your question.